# How to center values and columns in x axis MSChart using C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-visualization, mschart

I would like to move the x axis labels to the center of the x axis point and the chart columns as well

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: You can play with the AxisX.Minimum and the AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalOffset..

Comment: Using the AxisX.IntervallOffset I can only show or remove the lines not center them

Comment: Not true. You can freely move the grid; but you need to understand the x-values, the  AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval and  AxisX.MajorGrid.IntervalType as well. Play some more! Your concept of 'centering' however is opposite to what chart tries: It center the gridline over the datapoints; hnece my advice to 'play' with the values.

Comment: I could move the axis as you said, but what i really like to do is move the blue graphs and not the axis lines. Do you know how to handle that ?

Comment: You need to show the code you have tried and also how you add the data, esp. the x-values!

Comment: This is what i am doing `chart1.DataSource = dataset; chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Column of my dataset"; chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = 1; chart1.DataBind();` @TaW

Comment: I solved the problem using `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum` and `chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum` and then create custum Labels for each row Thanks for your help @TaW